# get html and text of highlighted (selected) elements (spans) and store text in hidden textarea

Tags: jquery

I want to know how to get the html and text of spans that are selected. Example html:

```
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
<span>c</span>
<span>d</span>
```

so if I highlighted with my cursor (a-b)...I would get

```
var storedHtml =     `<span>a</span> <span>b</span>`
var text = "ab"
```

and the text would be stored in a hidden textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few articles on this already:

- [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/jquery-get-the-highlighted-text)

  - Which references -> http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html
- Which in turn was a duplicate of: [Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)